# Differentiating Test site from Development Site (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net

We have a couple of ASP.NET applications running here at work and our users get the test site confused with the production site.  What is the best way to help the users know they are at the test site.  Is there a best practice for how this can be accomplished?  Maybe have a custom control or something on the screen display "TEST SITE"?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a different style sheet, that changes background colors and other elements, to make it immediately obvious which site I am using.